# As an author of a Pull Request in TFS, how does the reviewer know the PR needs to be re-reviewed?

Tags: project-management, team-foundation-server, pull-requests

I am project manager and I struggle with gaining the attention of the Reviewer of a pull request when the author has replied to a question from the Reviewer. In other words, the Reviewer initially put the PR in the "waiting for author" status because he had questions. The author has now replied with the answer to those questions.

What is the call to action for the Review to know the questions have been answered and the PR needs to be re-reviewed? TFS states "the author should let the reviewer know when the PR is ready to re-review" but it does not say how this is accomplished. My Reviewers look at the PR's assigned to them; however, if they still see the "Waiting for the Author" status with the orange clock, they assume the ball is still in the author's court.

So I guess my question is simply: how do you remove the "waiting for author" status when just Q&A is being exchanged and no rejection or additional commits have been made at this point?

Comment: As a member of the team you can setup an alert, which will notify you per email. Or your team member can @mention the other person.

Comment: "the author has now replied with the answer to those questions" - but how? In a face-to-face meeting, by phone, or by a shared-screen session, discussing the code changes? If yes, why didn't the reviewer change the PR state immediately at the end of the meeting? Or, if the author replied by email: why does the reviewer then need another notification, they already got an email? Reviewers should not delete that email until they changed the PR state.

Comment: The Reviewer is the CIO of a mid-sized software company and is not on-site to do a face-2-face meeting nor in a position to take a bunch of phone calls. The author replied via @mention the Reviewer and yes, this triggers a notification to the Reviewer; however, the Reviewer literally gets 400 emails per day. I need to rempove the "waiting for author" status to let the Reviewer know the ball is back in their court. Otherwise, the "at-a-glance" view in the Reviewer's "My Pull Requests" view of VSTS still shows the orange clock indicating waiting for the author.